# MYSQL Select based on date in the future producing duplicate, unpredictable results

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query that is supposed to take a number value (a number of days) from one table, add that value to the current date, then compare that date to rows with dates in another table and return every user ID and Event ID that match. (essentially, people set up reminders to go off X days before a certain event, and we're trying to run a query to see which reminders need to go out every day in a cronjob. Hopefully that makes sense.)

Unfortunately, I know I'm simply missing something. For one thing, the query returns double the set of results and apaprently flat out wrong results (it's pulling an Event that's a day AFTER the day). I'm definitely at the end of my knowledge-base on this one, and could use some help from folks who would know better.

- Users_Notifications.Alert is the number of days ahead of the event to remind the user
- Events_Root.EventDate is the date that the event happens.

  ```
  SELECT * FROM `Users_Notifications`, `Events_Root` WHERE 
  DATE( DATE_ADD( NOW(), INTERVAL Users_Notifications.Alert DAY ) ) 
      = DATE( Events_Root.EventDate );
  ```

The table definitions are as follows:

- **Users_Notifications:** ID, User_ID, Event_ID, Alert
- **Events_Root:** ID, Name, EventDate

Comment: Is there any common column for these 2 tables ?

Comment: Aren't you missing some `user_id` in where clause? For example let's have 3 records in `user_notifications` with Alert values: user A:1, user B:2, user C:3 and 2 records in `event_root` with dates: event 1: 2014-01-06, event 2: 2014-01-07. This query will result in 3 records: 2 with event 1 for users A,C and one with event 2 for user B.

Comment: @dev-null-dweller I'd guess that's definitely how we're getting 6 records when we should be getting three. Stupid oversight on my part. That said, we need to select all users with reminders corresponding to their date reminders, and I don't know how to do that!

Comment: Add the tables' definitions in your question.

Comment: Well you are selecting all events and users who want to be notified of them now. Maybe add table definitions, sample data and how current result differ from desired one.

Comment: Added table definitions! I thought I had described how the two results differ, but I clarified a bit more. It runs every day and needs to check any user-specified dates against event dates and return the user ID and event IDs of any event who's date matches that one criteria.

Comment: Looks like you are missing join condition `FORM Users_Notifications JOIN Events_Root ON(Users_Notifications.ID_Event = Events_Root.ID)`

Answer (score 0):

The NOW() function uses the local timezone. Make sure the timezone is correct on your server.

Comment: Thanks! That's a great point, and actually incredibly important since this is used nationally. For the purposes of this question, however, we're talking dates weeks out, so the timezone will likely not make a difference.

Comment: It is probably why you are seeing events show up for the next day.